# Change X-Axis on Report to show anything besides record count in lightning?

Tags: reporting, dashboard, custom-reports

In salesforce lightning, no matter what I do when I create a report and group by Account Owner and even another field the "X-Axis" only allows Record Count.  I do not want to show a record count, how can I group on any other field aside from Record Coutn on the X-Axis.  When I group by additional rows it allows me to change the Y-Axis, but never the "X-Axis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X axis is used to show things like sum or average values of a numeric field. To have other options available than Record Count, you need to modify the report to include at least one summary option.

[image: Summarize Field]

[image: Choose X Axis Options]

Different chart types will also offer different options (e.g. pie charts have fewer options than bar graphs).